# Case Expression with OR condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below `Case` expression that produces the correct results. When I add my "OR" condition the results change.

1. Why are results changing with the addition of "OR"?

   I would expect with the addition of the "OR" statement ID 1 should still be "Unassigned"

`Or` statement

```
--OR ( TABLEA.ROLE != 'RED' AND  CCP.STATUS = 'Active' 
  --AND  TO_CHAR(CCP.END_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') = '09/09/9000'
```

Full query

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN TABLEA.ROLE = 'RED'
                        AND TABLEA.ID IS NULL
                        AND CCP.STATUS = 'Active')
                        --OR (TABLEA.ROLE != 'RED' AND  CCP.STATUS = 'Active'
                              --AND TO_CHAR(CCP.END_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') = '09/09/9000')
                   THEN TABLEA.DT
              END
          ) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY TABLEA.HISTORYID DESC,
                  CASE WHEN TABLEA.ROLE = 'RED'
                       THEN TABLEA.DT
                  END ASC NULLS FIRST
                 ) OVER (PARTITION BY CCP.ID) IS NULL
      THEN 'Unassigned'
    --WHEN TABLEA.ROLE != 'RED' THEN 'Unassigned'
    WHEN TO_CHAR(CCP.END_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') != '09/09/9000'
         AND CCP.STATUS = 'Closed'
      THEN 'Closed'
    ELSE 'Assigned'
  END AS CURRENT_STATUS2
  FROM TABLEA
```

Results without `OR` statement:

```
 ID    CURRENT_STATUS2
 1       Unassigned
```

Results with `OR` statement: Should be Unassigned and not assigned

```
 ID    CURRENT_STATUS2
 1       Assigned
```

Comment: Syntax error...

Comment: Remember order of operations and your brackets...  this and that or this  is different from (this and that) or (this)

Comment: @jarlh Right. Is there a way to add the OR statement into my syntax correctly?

Comment: missing a final ) it seems

Comment: @Twelfth, got it thanks!

Comment: It contributes greatly to the understanding to indent the query correctly. Also, it would help to know the expected behavior. Difficult to say what is wrong without knowing it.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I've updated the question to give a better understanding of the ask and to indent correctly

Comment: You get `'Unassigned'` when `MAX(...)` is null. Maybe it's not null anymore because it yields new values that comply with the condition after the OR.

Answer (score 1):

Remembering the order (from comment above) this and that or this is different from (this and that) or (this)

Query should read:

```
CASE 
WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN (TABLEA.ROLE = 'RED' 
  AND TABLEA.ID IS NULL 
  AND CCP.STATUS = 'Active' )
  OR( HIST.ROLE != 'RED' AND  CCP.STATUS = 'Active' 
  AND TO_CHAR(CCP.END_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') = '01/01/3000' )
```

Comment: According to the Oracle docs [Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.5-en/operator-precedence.html), `OR` has a lower preceedence than `AND`.  Therefore your statement is false.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, Yes, I still notice that I'm getting the incorrect results. So, maybe rearragning the order may help?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes or perhaps the MAX statment is causing problems. Not sure

Answer (score 0):

Not easy code to read.   I think you are just a couple brackets away:

```
WHEN (TABLEA.ROLE = 'RED' 
AND TABLEA.ID IS NULL 
AND CCP.STATUS = 'Active')
OR ( TABLEA.ROLE != 'RED' AND  CCP.STATUS = 'Active' 
AND  TO_CHAR(CCP.END_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') = '09/09/9000')
```